# Unable to use gdal_calc from gdal to sum raster files

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to run the following line of code from Anaconda Prompt to add all all of the raster files in a directory/folder together using `gdal`:

```
for %f in (*.tif) do gdal_calc -A %f -B result.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc=A+B
```

However, when I run this, I receive the following error for each file I am trying to add together:

```
'gdal_calc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And when I try to run:

```
for %f in (*.tif) do gdal_calc.py -A %f -B result.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc=A+B
```

I receive this error pop-up for each file I am trying to add together (meaning I need to click out of hundreds of the same pop-up appearing over and over):

```
This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one ist already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.
```

Checking to make sure gdal is installed correctly, I run:

```
gdalinfo --version
```

and receive:

```
GDAL 2.3.3, released 2018/12/14
```

So it seems like I have `gdal` installed fine.

Is `gdal_calc` still a useable function? What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: By just running `gdal_calc.py`, does it open the editor?

Comment: Running just `gdal_calc.py` yields the message: `The system cannot execute the specified program.` and a pop-up reading: `This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one ist already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.` This happened both using Anaconda Prompt and OSGeo4W Shell.

Comment: Looks like the python file is not being able to open. Try opening any python file first (choose the app to open it, can be any text editor)

Answer (score 2):

The 'app associated' with gdal_calc.py is Python, so you have simply to type 'python' before gdal_calc.py.
The reason why this association has to be explicit on Windows is that the shebang of gdal_calc.py (#!/usr/bin/env python) has no sense in windows.

Comment: That makes sense, though I just reopened Anaconda Prompt, navigated to my directory and tried running `python gdal_calc.py`, which yielded: `python: can't open file 'gdal_calc.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, and then tried running: `python for %f in (*.tif) do gdal_calc.py -A %f -B result.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc=A+B`, which yielded: `python: can't open file 'for': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Comment: Do you have activated the virtual environment where GDAL is installed before?

Comment: The virtual environment component really confused me, I tried a tutorial on that, but it did not work for me, and I couldn't figure out why my virtual environment was not set up correctly. Do you know how I might check to see if this is all correct or how I might set it correctly if that is even feasible?